# Deleting and recreating EKCalendar

Tags: ios, calendar

In my app, I create events in an EKCalendar. I fetch the events online, and in order to refresh the events, I want to first delete the calendar (if it exists), recreate it, and then put the new events in there.

To instantiate the calendar I use

```
- (EKCalendar *)calendar {
    if (!_calendar) {
        NSArray *calendars = [self.store calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
        NSString *calendarTitle = @"MyCalendar";
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title matches %@", calendarTitle];
        NSArray *filtered = [calendars filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

        if ([filtered count]) {
            _calendar = [filtered firstObject];
        } else {
            _calendar = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent eventStore:self.store];
            _calendar.title = calendarTitle;
            _calendar.source = self.store.defaultCalendarForNewEvents.source;
            NSError *calendarErr = nil;
            BOOL calendarSuccess = [self.store saveCalendar:_calendar commit:YES error:&calendarErr];
            if (!calendarSuccess) {
                NSLog(@"Calendar Error = %@", [calendarErr localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
    }
    return _calendar;
}
```

To delete the calendar, I use

```
-(IBAction)deleteCalendar{
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.store removeCalendar:_calendar commit:YES error:&error];

}
```

Both methods work fine individually.
So, when I start the creation of events, I do the following:

```
[self deleteCalendar];//delete calendar and its events, in case it already exists
[self calendar];//create calendar
[self importEvents];//put events in calendar
```

Now, what I observe is the following:

On the first run of the app

- a calendar is created
- events are imported. (This is expected, and works just fine)

While the app is running, I trigger the above methods again with a button. With the following, for me puzzling, result:

- the calendar is deleted (expected result)
- NO calendar is created (**WHY? that is my main question**).The "if (!_calendar)" part of the method is considered FALSE, and nothing is executed.
- The 'importEvents' method runs through its regular hoopla, without any apparent errors, although I would expect something like a 'no source' error.

Please advise.

**UPDATE:**

This could be an indicator of what is happening, but I still don't get it:

After a while, the events appear in a *different* calendar, i.e. not the calendar called 'myCalendar', but another, iCloud based calendar, apparently the one that at that point is the **defaultCalendarForNewEvents**. However, that also doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so, what is happening:
I have deleted the Calendar from the store, effectively, but a reference to that calendar actually was still hanging around in my app.
I solved it as follows:

```
-(IBAction)deleteCalendar:(id)sender{
    NSError *error = nil;
    if(_calendar){
        [self.store removeCalendar:_calendar commit:YES error:&error];
    }
    _calendar = nil;
}
```

I hope this is useful to someone